# Single battery for different voltage components

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc-motor, stepper-motor

So I have a 12V DC motor and a 6V stepper motor. Ideally, I would like both of them to draw from the same 12V battery pack (due to build constraints). The DC motor will be fine but the extra 6V running through the stepper could damage it, right?

Is there a way I could have one power supply (12V battery pack) and have both motors drawing from it? So DC motor drawing 12V and stepper motor drawing only 6V. I've read about voltage dividers, but would that mean wasting 6V in the circuit through resistance?

- Can I use a buck converter in series between the DC and stepper motors to step down to 6V?
- Or can I simply connect them in parallel so that 4 batteries to go the stepper motor then 8 batteries go to the DC motor, then they both connect to ground?

Comment: If you have additional material for your question, please use the edit button to add it directly, rather than leaving it in comments. Actually, using 12V to power your stepper motor can result in improved performance, as long as you use a driver that can control the current.

Comment: Either of those options would work, but the second one is not a good idea as it will result in uneven drain on your batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is the best one - using a buck converter- which increases overall system power efficiency.

the second option will drain the cells in you pack with different characteristics- which will effect the overall battery pack performance - which is highly not recommended.

4 of your batteries will be overused and 4 of your batteries will be under used

Comment: Would it be better to do it in series or parallel? (buck converter in series between DC and stepper) or (parallel wherein the buck converter is inline with the stepper on their own path)

Comment: since your are looking for output voltage controlling. go with Series.make sure there will be a stepper controller

Comment: Cheers, I'm using an MG996R, so the controller is built in I believe.

Comment: Hey you posted it as stepper. its not a stepper motor the part number is servo motor. No worries the proposed method will work.....

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry I did mean servo.

Comment: No problem.. all the best